# How to get users by their roles using hibernate criteria in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Spring with Hibernate in my project. I want to get users by a particular role using Hibernate criteria. My User model is connected with Role model using `@ManyToMany` annotation:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
)
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}
```

and here is my criteria in my `UserDaoHibernate`:

```
public List<User> getUsersByRole(List<Role> roles) {
    List users = getSession().createCriteria(User.class)
            .add(Restrictions.in("roles", roles)).list();
    return users;
}
```

I am getting DataIntegrityViolationException when executing this criteria. Am i missing something or is there any correct way of getting users by their roles?

Comment: Try to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20427782/1679310) and also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26718407/1679310) for some more ideas about many-to-many querying

Comment: Can You please tell me what is wrong with my criteria?

Comment: In general, you've used many-to-many, which is very difficult to use for querying. I tried to explain that many times: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15510748/1679310. If you will use many-to-one, your searching will becom more simple and you can use this simple approach: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20426734/1679310

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured it out by following the trigger in the comment and this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4032518/2072900)

This solution is not completely solve the problem as it intends to get only users by one role, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood you, but this method works for me:

```
List<User> findUsersByRoles_RoleIdIn(List<Integer> roles);
```